# Find out what winhook is causing mouse lag with voip software and 12 button mouse

Tags: windows-10, mouse, voip

Running windows 10, I recently got a 12 button mouse and I noticed that when i run any sort of voip software (Discord, Ventrilo, Skype, etc), my mouse clicks will sometimes not register. Or sometimes the release of the click doesnt register. This also includes any of the 12 other buttons which are bound to keyboard buttons so it acts as if i am still pressing the buttons. Even more confusing, sometimes my typing will be backwards until i click on various buttons. And as soon as i close any of that software, the mouse works perfectly fine again.

Originally I thought it was the generic 12 button mouse I had, so I bought a name brand one, but the issue still happens. And when i use a regular mouse everything works fine.

So after spending some time searching, I am currently thinking it has to do with how windows handles these gaming mice and specifically the windows hooks for mouse input. I dont know for sure if this is it, but im positive it has something to do with it and im not really sure how to monitor what exactly is happening when running voip software.

I have tried uninstalling/installing drivers, swapping mice, different computer with windows 10, virus scans, different keyboards, monitoring the voip software api calls, etc. but i havent been able to really determine what the issue is or how to fix it.

I am utterly baffled as to how to determine what the root cause of this is. Has anyone experienced something like this before?

Comment: This probably sounds like Tech Support Stock Answer 0001, but, have you updated the firmware for the mouse recently?  Also, check the mfr website for any known issues with VOIP apps.  It would also be helpful to know the specific brand/model of mouse involved.  Keep in mind that most "extra button" mice actually load a secondary keyboard device, so you can test which device is bunged up by hooking up a 10-key pad or a gaming keypad to see if it is also affected.

Comment: Its a logitech g600, but i had some generic brand before and had same issue so i didnt think it was the mouse itself. And yep the firmware is up to date. I'll try to dig out a joystick or something to test, but i'm thinking it might be that these mice emulate keypresses, whereas a joystick has its own inputs that fire. Not really sure though.

Comment: Correct. If you have access to a 10-key pad or a Logitech G15 gamepad, that would load a keyboard driver instance when connected.  Or, a second keyboard if you've a spare. Another possible test is to use the PS2 mouse adapter and PS2 port, rather than a USB port.  That'll isolate the USB Root Hub drivers.